# I am writing a program to find the only appear once number in an given array like {1,2,2},{1,2,1,2,4},{1,0,1} using nested for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

in the first loop, I assign every element inside the loop to tmp , and in the second loop, I compare the tmp with all elements(Include itself) in the array, if tmp == the element, then add count(Record num of time).After the inside loop, if count==1(only equals with itself)  , then jump out the out loop and return the tmp.

I can't find the logical issues,please help me to find problem in my logic or code
Several cases were passed, except {1,0,1} , which output 1 instead of 0

```
/**
 *
 * @author Ryan
 */
public class SingleNum {


 public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
        int count=0,tmp=0;

        for(int j = 0;j < nums.length;j++)
        {
            tmp = nums[j];
            for(int i = 0;i < nums.length;i++)
            {
            if(tmp == nums[i])
            count+=1;   
            }
            if(count == 1)
            break;              
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    class Solution {
   
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array [] = {1,0,1};
        System.out.println(singleNumber(array));
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you did incorrectly was not resetting count to 0.  However,
I added a few more optimizations.

- as soon as count exceeds 1, stop the inner loop and continue the outer one
- if the inner loop continues successfully, you know that count was only 1 so
  you can immediately return tmp.
- if you completely finish the outer loop, that means no values occurred just once, so return -1.  This means that -1 should not be a legitimate value.  If it is, some other method of showing this should be used.
- finally, if more than one value occurs once, only the first will be returned.

```
public class SingleNum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = { 3,3, 2, 2, 4, 5,5 };
        System.out.println(singleNumber(array)); // prints 4
    }
    
    public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
        int tmp = 0;
        outer: for (int num : nums) {
            int count = 0;
            tmp = num;
            for (int val : nums) {
                if (tmp == val) {
                    count++;
                    // as soon as count > 1, stop this inner loop
                    if (count > 1) {
                        continue outer;
                    }
                }
            }
            return tmp;
        }
        return -1; // -1 shows no single values.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Foremost try avoiding nested for loops because they waste time to try finding optimal solutions.

- You were comparing the same number with itself but it was balanced with count value as 1 for a single occurrence number and you were not resetting the count value to zero after the nested for loop end.

  ```
   /**
   *
   * @author Ryan
   */
  public class SingleNum {


  public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
   int count=0,tmp=0;

   for(int j = 0;j < nums.length;j++)
   {
       tmp = nums[j];
       count = 0;
       for(int i = 0;i < nums.length;i++)
       {
       if(i != j && tmp == nums[i])
       count+=1;   
       }
       if(count == 0)
       break;              
   }
   return tmp;
   }
   /**
    * @param args The command-line arguments
    */
   class Solution {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int array [] = {1,0,1};
       System.out.println(singleNumber(array));
   }
   }
  ```

Comment: thanks,Ashish,it works.And i =! j should be i !=j

Comment: You tell the OP to not use nested loops but you add in an inefficiency by comparing `i to j`  So now for an array length of `n`, you are doing `2*n-1` comparisons instead of `n` comparisons.  Just leave out the first comparison altogether and look for a count = 1.

Comment: @WJS you are right, comparing would decrease efficiency, would add a proper solution latter